# Issue with initial focus while scanning QR-code with ZBar

Tags: ios, qr-code, zbar-sdk, autofocus

I created an app which uses ZBar to scan QR-codes. While testing I noticed that there are problems with auto-focus.
When I aim my iPad at a QR-code prior to starting the scan, it shows a green rectangle around the QR-code and it doesn't scan. I need to reaim the iPad on another object to focus on, and then aim back at the QR-code.

If I don't aim at a QR-code prior to scanning it works. I just need to aim at the QR-code from the moment the Zbar view is launched.

I'm using minimum iOS 6 and iPads 2 and 3.

I used the code as described on the website of ZBar so nothing special to note there.
I'm thinking that it's a problem with ZBar itself. Are there other people experiencing this problem or have a solution for this?

Comment: actually I never found a solution. The solution provided is to check it on other devices. I don't have other devices and knowing it works on other devices doesn't really solve the problem :).

Comment: imeet your same problem，ithink it is not device reson，ithink the lib have problem

Comment: @Stephan Celis I also phase this type of problem ... good question. :) If you got solution then share it.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the library of ZBar. Didn't find a solution though

Comment: @Stephan Celis Thanks for Replay

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it on some other iPad devices? Maybe it's problem only with your iPad. What about iPhone? My scanner is also based on Zbar - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qr-scan/id568762816?ls=1&mt=8 you can try it if it works as you want..

Answer (score 0):

We were facing same issue with Zbar, we solved it by putting a 2 sec delay before dismissing model view.